# Formatting a list with an existing text file in Python

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to create a list from an existing text file in python.  The text file is a list of 27 names, DOBs and school Ranks where each line represents a different person.  I want the it to read

```
First         Last         DOB        Rank
------------------------------------------
```

with the data then listed for each category from the text file.

So far I have:

```
print("First      Last          DOB         Rank   ")
print("--------------------------------------------")
file = open("input_file.txt","r")
list = file.readlines()
for line in list:
    list = line.split(',')
    print(list[0:26])
file.close()
print(file)
```

I was able to get it to give the first line but went back and made changes and now I am completely lost.  I keep getting the error that the type is not iterable.

Comment: start by using  different name that `list` for your variable, then don't change it within the loop

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using a builtin name, `list`, as a variable, and trying to iterate over it. Use the variable name `list_` or `lines` instead. You are also trying to change the variable inside the loop which is never a good idea.

As an example:

```
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = line.split(',')
    print(line[0:26])
```